# MySQL - Subtract sums from two different tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to do join table `points_minus` and do something like `(SUM(p.points) - SUM(m.points)) AS points` instead of doing this `return $points - $this->getMUserPoints($user_id);` which is a bit much imo. And if it can be done without using sub queries that would be great.

```
    /**
    * Get plus user points.
    *
    * @param (int) $user_id
    */
    public function getUserPoints($user_id) {
        if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(points) FROM points_plus WHERE user_id = ?"))
        {
            $q->bind_param("i", $user_id);
            $q->execute();

            $q->bind_result($points);

            $q->fetch();
            $q->close();
            return $points - $this->getMUserPoints($user_id);
        }
            return false;
    }


    /**
    * Get minus user points.
    *
    * @param (int) $user_id
    */
    public function getMUserPoints($user_id) {
        if($q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(points) FROM points_minus WHERE user_id = ?"))
        {
            $q->bind_param("i", $user_id);
            $q->execute();

            $q->bind_result($points);

            $q->fetch();
            $q->close();
            return $points;
        }
            return false;
    }
```

Got this far ... but it's returning a negative number:

```
"SELECT (SUM(p.points) - SUM(m.points) )
FROM points_plus p
LEFT JOIN
points_minus m 
ON p.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE p.user_id = ?
GROUP BY p.user_id"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate:

```
select sum(points) 
from (select points from points_plus where user_id = ?
      union all
      select -points from points_minus where user_id = ?) t
```

Another version, but I am not sure if this is correct syntax for `MySql`:

```
select (select sum(points) from points_plus where user_id = ?) -
       (select sum(points) from points_minus where user_id = ?)
```

Comment: The second one works ... but aren't those two sub queries?

Comment: @ciprian, yes it is subquery, but it s not correlated subquery. You have to use subqueries. You can not do this with join because you will get meanengless result.

Comment: ok. thank you very much for your help. but to your knowledge ... is it a better than what I had before? the two methods. ..